# Cannot export a typescript class to a webpack project

Tags: typescript, webpack, fabricjs

I have inherited a project with some just JS (written in a typescript library). I am trying to update the project to use Webpack, but am getting issues loading the ts library into my JS script.

The module has installed via Yarn/NPM OK (as well as it's dependencies), I updated the typescript class to the following:

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

export class PlatePreview {
```

I also updated the tsconfig.json to identify it as a module

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "watch": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "declaration": false
    },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

My full webpack config is as follows:

```
const Path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const PATHS = {
  MODULES: Path.resolve('node_modules'), // your node_modules folder name, or full path
  SC: Path.resolve('../silvercommerce/src'),
  FILES_PATH: '../', // relative path from your css files to your other files, such as images and fonts
  ROOT: Path.resolve(), // the root path, where your webpack.config.js is located.
  SRC: Path.resolve('src'), // the root path, where your webpack.config.js is located.
  SCSS: Path.resolve('src/scss'), // the root path to your source files
  CSS: Path.resolve('css'), // the root path to your source files
  JS: Path.resolve('javascript'), // the root path to your built files
};

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/jquery/dist/jquery.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/tether/dist/js/tether.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/jquery-match-height/dist/jquery.matchHeight-min.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/jquery-zoom/jquery.zoom.min.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js`
        ],
        script: [
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/fabric/dist/fabric.js`,
            `${PATHS.MODULES}/@ilateral/bestplate-previewer/src/plate-preview.ts`,
            `${PATHS.SC}/javascript/script.js`,
            `${PATHS.SRC}/javascript/script.js`
        ],
        bundlecss: [
            `${PATHS.SCSS}/bundle.scss`
        ],
        editor: [
            `${PATHS.SCSS}/editor.scss`
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: PATHS.ROOT,
        filename: 'javascript/[name].js',
        publicPath: PATHS.ROOT
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                    },
                },
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'images',
                            publicPath: '../images',
                            name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                        },
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            publicPath: '../fonts'
                        }
                    }
            ]   
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {
                path: PATHS.ROOT,
                filename: 'css/[name].css',
                chunkFilename: 'css/[id].css',
            }
        )
    ],
    resolve: {
        // Expose Jquery Globally
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
            fabric: 'fabric'
        }
    }
};
```

Everything else works OK, and webpack generates the JS files, but when I add the following to my script.js:

```
import PlatePreview from '@ilateral/bestplate-previewer';

var preview = new PlatePreview(`PlatePreview${id}`);
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: _ilateral_bestplate_previewer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor`

I also tried `new PlatePreview.PlateReview(`PlatePreview${id}`);`, but that also generated a similar error.

I also tried changing the import to `import { PlatePreview } from '@ilateral/bestplate-previewer';` but still get the same error.

Anyone got any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks,

Mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not got this working properly, but if anyone stumbles upon a similar issue, I managed to get some success by altering my `tsconfig` to export `module: "ES2015"`, EG:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "watch": true,
        "module": "ES2015",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "declaration": false
    },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

This generates a js lib with the correct exports that I can then include in my webpack script.

This is still a bit fiddly, but does seem to work for my needs.